# How do you count a multidimensional array to put in a foreach loop (in php)?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

How do you count an array for a foreach loop?  Also, is this the best way to write this code or is there more of a catchall?  I have a 3 dimensional array(3 levels).

Here is an example from  print_r

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
   (
        [0] => 17
        [audit_inspectionID] => 17
        [1] => 2016-08-15
        [created] => 2016-08-15
        [2] => 2016-08-15 09:52:28
        [modified] => 2016-08-15 09:52:28
        [class_answer] => Array
            (
                [0] => Needs Improvement     
                [1] => Need To Correct     
                [2] => Needs Immediate Action     
            )
   )

)
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($requirements as $key => $value){
    $newArray[] = $value['audit_inspectionID'];
    $newArray[] = $value['requirement'];
    $newArray[] = $value['class_answer'];
    $newArray[] = $value['repeat_answer'];
    $newArray[] = $value['class_answer'];
    $newArray[] = $value['actionID'];
    $newArray[] = $value['action_link'];

    print "<div id='inspection_view" . $value['audit_inspectionID'] . "' style='display:inline'>
        <table id='actions_table' class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped bg-info'>
          <thead>
              <th align='center'>" . value['requirement'] . " </th>
              ". if ($corporate_admin == 'true') { ."
                <a id='" . $value['audit_inspectionID'] . "' class='btn btn-danger  pull-right remove1' href=' + '#' + '>Remove</a><a id='edit" . $value['audit_inspectionID'] ."' class='btn btn-warning pull-right edit1' href=#>Edit</a></th>
              ". } ."
              </thead><tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>
```

How can I count this array for this for loop?

```
                 ". for (x = 0; x< count($value[class_answer]) ; x++){ 
                      $value[class_answer] 
                  } ."
                  <br>
                  ". $value[repeat_answer] ."
                  <br>
                  ". if ($value[actionID] != 0) { 
                    $value[action_link]
                  } ."
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>";/**/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a other statements like `for` or `if` inside a `print` statement. End the `print` statement, then use a new statement to do what you want.

```
print "<div id='inspection_view" . $value['audit_inspectionID'] . "' style='display:inline'>
    <table id='actions_table' class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped bg-info'>
          <th align='center'>" . value['requirement'] . " </th>
          <tr>
              <td>";
foreach ($value['class_answer'] as $ans) {
    print "$ans ";
}
print "<br>
      ".$value[repeat_answer]."
      <br>";
if ($value['actionID'] != 0) {
    print $value['action_link'];
}
print "</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>";
```

Comment: I forgot about that, kept trying to make it open and close between statements.  Makes sense.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the statement and print out later.
I would do this

```
print "<div id='inspection_view" . $value['audit_inspectionID'] . "' style='display:inline'>
    <table id='actions_table' class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped bg-info'>
          <th align='center'>" . value['requirement'] . " </th>
          <tr>
              <td>";
          $count=0;
          for (x = 0; x< count($value[class_answer]) ; x++){ 
              $count++; 
          }
print "<br>". $value[repeat_answer] ."<br>";
          if ($value[actionID] != 0) { 
              print $value[action_link];
           }
                  print "</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>";
```

The number of elements in $value[class_answer] is $count

```
print $count
```

Comment: Surrounded by  foreach loop I am presuming